How to hide header on scroll in react-native with Reanimated 3
I'm trying to hide header in react native expo app on scroll. When I scroll down header should hide smoothly and reappear again as soon as I scroll up regardless where I am on the page (not when I scroll all the way to top of the page). I did find some example for earlier version of reanimated but not sure how to convert it to reanimated 3 since diffClamp cant be used in reanimated 3.
here is that example:
const headerHeight=70;
    const scrollY=new Animated.Value(0);
    const diifClampScrollY=Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, headerHeight);
    const headerY=new Animated.interpolate(diffClampScrollY, {
         inputRange: [0, headerHeight],
         outputRange: [0, -headerHeight]
    })


after that transform is added in styles for Animated.View
<Animated.View style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        height: headerHeight,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        zIndex: 1000,
        elevation: 1000,
        transform: [{translateY: headerY}]
     }}></Animated.View>


and in ScrollView we add scroll handler event like this
<Animated.ScrollView
        bounces={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        style={{paddingTop: headerHeight}}
        onScroll={Animated.event([
            {
             native.Event {contentOffset: {y:scrollY}}
            }
        ])}
    </Animated.ScrollView>


What i tried is to convert all to use reanimated 3 but without any success.
